# AFNetworking : Receiving “numbers” instead of GET Request text

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am trying to set up a GET Request using AFHTTPRequestOperationManager and AFHTTPResponseSerializer. However, instead of receiving a proper GET Request response (like this one, which I got using Charles debugging proxy) I receive a lot of random numbers. I tried to use the solution from this topic ([AFNetworking - JSON: Receiving "numbers" instead of JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666633/afnetworking-json-receiving-numbers-instead-of-json)), but I did not succeed as my dictionary was null.

```
GET /scripts/wsisa.dll/WService=wsedumeritasil/seplog01 HTTP/1.1
Host: skyward.iscorp.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: BIGipServerSkywardPool18-Meritas=4200349962.47873.0000; BIGipServerSkywardWebspeed=2388410634.47873.0000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10) AppleWebKit/600.1.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/600.1.25
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

Here's my code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
AFHTTPResponseSerializer *serializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
serializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
manager.responseSerializer = serializer;
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] ;
NSDictionary *dict = @{
                       @"Host" : @"skyward.iscorp.com",
                       };
[manager GET:@"https://skyward.iscorp.com/scripts/wsisa.dll/WService=wsedumeritasil/seplog01"
  parameters:dict
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
         NSError *error;
         NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:&error];
      NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", [jsonDict description]);   
     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"error");
     }];
```

And here`s my output:

```
<3c21444f 43545950 45204854 4d4c2050 55424c49 4320222d 2f2f5733 432f2f44 54442048 ...
Dictionary: (null)
```

Comment: I visited that site and I see a HTML login page, not JSON.

Comment: Those "numbers" are the output of the `NSData` object stored in `responseObject`. The data represents the text of the HTML page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That long sequence of hexadecimal numbers is just the standard hex representation of a `NSData`. If you convert that hexadecimal representation of the `NSData` into a string, you can see it says:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD H
```

That would appear to be the start of a HTML page.

If, rather than logging `responseObject`, you log `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`, you'll see the full contents of the HTML page that you've accidentally retrieved.

The fact that you are using a `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` (which I'm guessing you did because `AFJSONResponseSerializer` wasn't working?) would seem to support the hypothesis. Generally if you were receiving JSON response, you'd stick with `AFJSONResponseSerializer` (which would do the `JSONObjectWithData` for you).

You should confirm the API with the provider of the web service, make sure that you've performed the necessary authentication and/or are using the API correctly. Clearly the request is not well formed or the URL is incorrect or some necessary authentication hasn't taken place.